# Best way available to convert a PDF of any version into a scanned / flatten PDF file

Tags: php, fpdf, ghostscript

I would like to know is there a way which will help me convert a PDF which is not scanned (can be modified in Acrobat Pro) into a file which is scanned / flatted (cant be edited in Acrobat Pro).

I have been using FPDF library but it seems that it is not able to recognize if the PDF is flatten / not in 1st place and depending on this it is triggering some different actions.

I have tried my best to study the FPDF library and I think it checks for the 'xref' position and decides  to take which steps should be taken.
But in my case I have 2 files, one is flatted and one not and FPDF cant determine the difference itself. Both these files are of version 1.4. I have also read that FPDF has a limitation of processing pdfs which are only 1.4 version.

Comment: How do you define such a "flatten" PDF file? What is your use case for that?

Comment: In my case, if a file which cant be edited in Acrobat Pro is flattened. I am working on a code which was inherited to me. In comes a new request and while I am trying to achieve that I realize this new issue that FPDF cant recognize if the file is  flattened or not.

Comment: How did FPDF determine whether the file is "flattened" or not?

Comment: FPDF checks for the xref property within PDF file and then it understands that it is flattened. But I am not sure about this.

Comment: Is there any error message given when you try to use invalid input data?

Comment: No error message at all. but since I know the files which are flatten and which not so I am kind of unsure if FPDF understands the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Ghostscript's pdfimage device which will render the entire content to an image, and then wrap that up as a PDF file. There's absolutely no possibility of extracting anything from that without running it through OCR software. That 'sounds lie' what you want, though its hard to be certain.

I'm afraid that I don't think your understanding of 'flattened' can be correct. All PDF files will have an xref, so the presence or absence of such a keyword doesn't tell you if the PDF is 'flattened', whatever your user/manager means by that rather vague term.

The absence of a 'xref' could mean that the file is a PDF 1.5 or better version, and is using a compressed xref. Nothing to do with it being flattened, but any PDF consumer will have to treat such a file differently to a PDF 1.4 or below file.

Comment: Hello KenS,Thank you for your reply and answer. I now understand that my 1st assumption about xref was wrong and it does not tell me if the file is flattened or not. But please now can you let me know any possible way to find out if PDF is flatten or not? Thank you.

Comment: well without knowing what you mean by 'flattened', no. Some people use 'flattened' to mean that any transparent content has been rendered. Others that fotns have been replaced by vectors, and still others refer technically to the representation of curves as a series of straight lines (flatness). It is possible to analyse the content of a PDF file, and detect that the entire content is an image (Acrobat can do this), but Ghostscript doesn't currently offer this, and I don't offhand know of any other software which does.